# Is the minimum-variance unbiased estimator (MVUE) for P^2 of Bernoulli(p) asymptotically normally distributed

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

let$ ~X_1, ...X_n ~$be iid Bernoulli$(p)$ let $W_n$ is the MVUE of $p^2$

Find $W_n$ and determine
it is asymptotically normally distributed in the sense that $ \sqrt{
n}(W_n − \mu)$

converges in distribution to a normal distribution, for some constant $\mu$.

I try:

This family of distribution belongs to the exponential family and the complete and sufficient statistics is  $Y_n = ∑X_i $  binomial$(n,p)$

I have found the MVUE of  $ p^2$  is $(Y_n ^2$-$Y_n$)/$n(n-1)  $   by Lehmann 
 and Scheffe Theorem

Now, I know the MLE of $p$ is $Y_n/n $

Then by CLT we have,
$\sqrt n(Y_n/n - p) $ converges in distribution to $N(0, p(1-p))$

from here I tried to use the delta method but I cannot proceed because
I got $n$ on the right-hand side. Is that enough to say it is not convergent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sqrt n \left(W_n - p^2\right) & = \sqrt n \left(\frac {Y_n^2 - Y_n}{n(n-1)} - p^2\right) \\ &= \sqrt n \left(\left(\frac{Y_n}n\right)^2 - p^2\right) + \sqrt n Y_n^2 \left(\frac 1{n(n-1)} - \frac1{n^2}\right) - \frac {Y_n}{\sqrt n (n-1)}\\
&= \sqrt n \left(\left(\frac{Y_n}n\right)^2 - p^2\right) + \frac{Y_n^2}{n\sqrt n (n-1) } - \frac {Y_n}{\sqrt n (n-1)}
\end{align}

Since $\sqrt n \left(\frac {Y_n}n - p \right) \to_{d} \mathcal N\left(0, p(1-p)\right) $ then by using delta method with $g(p) = p^2$ $$\sqrt n \left(\left(\frac {Y_n}n\right)^2 - p^2 \right) \to_{d} \mathcal N\left(0, 2p\times p(1-p)\right)$$

On the other hand $\frac {Y_n}n \to_{a.s.} p$ $$\frac{Y_n^2}{n\sqrt n (n-1) } - \frac {Y_n}{\sqrt n (n-1)} \to_{a.s.} 0$$ this proves that $$\sqrt n \left(W_n - p^2 \right) \to_{d} \mathcal N\left(0, 2p\times p(1-p)\right)$$

Comment: I think I am supposed to find the convergence in distribution is normal with mean and variance,sorry I can not see connection to get that

Comment: I edit my answer and add details. Tell me if you understand it now.